# ContentEditable DIV - disabling drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

Is it possible to disable the drag-and-drop functionality on elements which have the contentEditable attribute set to true.

I have the following HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><meta charset="utf-8"><head><title>ContentEditable</title></head>
<body>
    <div contenteditable="true">This is editable content</div>
    <span>This is not editable content</span>
    <img src="bookmark.png" title="Click to do foo" onclick= "foo()">
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

The main problem I'm facing is that it is possible to drag and drop the image into the DIV and it gets copied (along with the title and the click handler)

Answer (score 32):

The following snippet will prevent your div from receiving dragged content:

```
jQuery('div').bind('dragover drop', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

I ([and several others](http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/)) find this api to be strange and counter-intuitive, but it does prevent a contenteditable from receiving dragged content in all browsers except IE8 (including IE9 beta).  As of yet, I cannot prevent IE8 from accepting contenteditable.

I'll update this answer if I find a way to do so.

Comment: Preventing dragover has no effect for me on FF/Chrome@Mac. Preventing drop neither.

Comment: Edit: I was wrong. Preventing `drop` worked. But preventing `dragover` only on Chrome.

Comment: I'm using `ondragover="return false" ondrop="return false"` and I don't see any problems. Is `event.preventDefault()` required here ?

Comment: A react equivalent to this is `onDrop`.

Answer (score 5):

I have found that I need to set the dropEffect to 'none' for both dragenter and dragover to reject a drag.  If you don't bind dragenter, the cursor will flicker when the drag enters the element, so the code would be:

```html
<div contenteditable="true" ondragenter="event.preventDefault(); event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'none'" ondragover="event.preventDefault(); event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'none'">This is editable content</div>
<span>This is not editable content</span>
<img src="bookmark.png" title="Click to do foo" onclick= "foo()">
```

Answer (score 4):

Interesting, I don't know the drag and drop interface well enough to be sure, but it looks like there's some sort of bug here.  I modified your code slightly to add a handler for the drop event on the editable div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ContentEditable</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div contenteditable="true" ondrop="window.alert('dropped!');return false;">This is editable content</div>
    <span>This is not editable content</span>
    <span>
        <img src="bookmark.png" title="Click to do foo" onclick="foo()">
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm testing in Firefox 3.7 alpha: if I drag the image on to the middle of the text the event fires, I get an alert, and the `return false` stops the image being dropped.  However if I drag on to the start of the text the event doesn't fire but the image gets inserted inside the div.  Mind you, in Firefox 3.6 and Chromium 6.0 the event doesn't fire at all, so either I've completely misunderstood how it works or none of it works well enough right now to rely on.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome and Firefox, you have to cancel the `ondragover` event for the `ondrag` event to fire. I would also recommend canceling the `ondragenter` and `ondragleave` events just to be sure.

http://jsbin.com/itugu/2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ContentEditable</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div contenteditable="true" ondragenter="return false;" ondragleave="return false;" ondragover="return false;" ondrop="window.alert('dropped!');return false;">This is editable content</div>
    <span>This is not editable content</span>
    <span>
        <img src="bookmark.png" title="Click to do foo" onclick="foo()">
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

This behavior isn't a bug; in the HTML5 specification it says that `ondragover` must be canceled for `ondrag` to fire. It doesn't make any sense to do it this way, so I hope they change it soon. See http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [dragstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragstart_event) event and prevent the default behavior. This works in all modern browsers.

```js
document.addEventListener('dragstart', event => {
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">This is editable content</div>
<span>This is not editable content</span>
<img width="20" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/barbie-pink/bookmark-5-xxl.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to disable all mousedown events on the image?

```
$('img').on('mousedown', function(){
    return false;
});
```